# Best way to change CSS in multiple components of the same component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that i'm using 3 times with different data which I am able to complete with the following code;

```
    <div>
      <Container className="mt-5">
        <Row>
          {author_data.map((authors) => {
            return (
              <Col key={authors.id} className="pe-5 ps-5">
                <Author
                  key={authors.id}
                  image={authors.image}
                  author={authors.author}
                  description={authors.description}
                  handleClick={(author) => setAuthor(author)}
                />
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
```

However Im looking to change the CSS on each component once I click on one of the Author components. something like the below using native JS.

```
document.getElementById("author1").classList.add("addGrayScale");
document.getElementById("author2").classList.add("addGrayScale");
document.getElementById("author3").classList.remove("addGrayScale");
```

I have used the useState and useContext hooks but I can't seem to get it to work because the Author component will receive the same props. Should I create separate components for each Author? or is there another way to do this.

Comment: Are you able to change the code for `Author`?

Comment: You need to [lift state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to an ancestor component. Maybe `authors` should have a `selected` property.

Comment: @HanchenJiang Yes I can change the code for Author

Comment: @isherwood i have tried to lift the state but when passing it back down it passes it to all Author componenets. Is there a way to only pass it to certain Author components?

Comment: That's not the right strategy. You should pass a property to _each_ component, and its value should determine behavior. The property values should be on an individual basis.